# Comparative words after the subject

Tags: relative-clauses, comparatives, relative-pronouns

I'm really having trouble figuring out how to describe a clause describing a subject which contains a comparative adjective (or an adjective of equality). For example:

> Children [shorter than four feet] are not allowed on the ride.
>
> Words [larger than eight letters] confuse me.
>
> The number [equal to 6] is the correct answer.
>
> Which word [synonymous with "sad"] is also a color?

Is this a relative clause without a relative pronoun? Also, would these clauses be considered non-restrictive, therefore requiring commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge and internet research goes these are all (or should be, depending on what meaning you are trying to convey) **restrictive relative clauses with a zero-pronoun**.

```
Children [that are] shorter than four feet are not allowed on the ride.

Words [that are] larger than eight letters confuse me.

The number [that is] equal to 6 is the correct answer.

Which word [that is] synonymous with "sad" is also a color?
```

The words in brackets are what is left out by the zero-realisation.

If you use the relative clause to add some information that does not change the meaning of the modified noun then you would have a **non-restrictive relative clause** and would have to use commas.

```
Words, larger than eight letters, confuse me.
```

This would then result in the meaning of the sentence changing to *words confuse you* (because non-restrictive relative clauses add information that can be omitted, generally speaking) although this would be a weird example of a non-restrictive relative clause.

I hope this helps somewhat.